# AS3 - Zoom feature with a movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Can any body tell how to zoom a movie clip like this: http://www.backspace.com/mapapp/

The Fist map on that page, you can zoom a particular region by draging a box around it.

Are there any tutorial or links where this functionality is explained.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

simply rescale a vector graphic and reposition it according to the mouseX/mouseY of the display object, or localX/localY of the mouse event.  it's really simple.  use a Tween engine (like Tweener) to animate the transition.

Comment: OK. I am not very good AS3 coder. Could you give me sample or tutorials reference?

Answer (score 0):

The zoom function can be achieved trough the `scale` property of the MovieClip.

The box drawing can be made with the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` and `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` events.

Here's a very helpful link for drag & drop and draw functionality: 
http://www.flashandmath.com/basic/dragdroptour/dd_tour2.html

You can draw a box during you move the mouse and when you relese the mouse you rescale the MovieClip to match the box size and reposition it's position with the x and y properties.

Comment: Thank you but i need same tutorial like which i refered. Because i am not good in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a `map` with the size of `100x100.`
We also have a county called `A` sized `20x10` at position `50x10.`

To calculate how much needs to be zoomed we take the larger axis of A (20) and the same axis of the map (100).
`100 / 20 = 5.`
The map needs to be zoomed 5 times.

```
mapMC.scaleX = mapMC.scaleY = 5;
```

However now we also need to move the map to the right position.
The map size is now 5 times bigger (500x500). We now calculate the position of A on the new resized map.

```
5 * 50 = 250
5 * 10 = 50
```

Now you move the map to position -250, -50. We need to move it in the negative direction.

```
mapMC.x = -250;
mapMC.y = -50
```

Comment: Thank you but i need same tutorial like which i refered. Because i am not good in AS3.

Comment: I'm afraid there are no tutorials for EXACTLY that but you should start with the very basis of AS3. Here's a good link http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flash/index.htm